# Удалить часть строки в Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Допустим, есть строка @"Hello". Скажем мне надо удалить "e". Как правильно это сделать? Мне известна только позиция буквы равная 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *s = [@"Hello" mutableCopy];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, 1); // первый аргумент - позиция буквы, второй количество символов
[s deleteCharactersInRange:range];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello";
hello = [hello stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Hello" withString:@"Hllo"];
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *helloStr = @"Hello";
helloStr = [helloStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"e" withString:@""];
```